# Calculate a tip & total, without rounding errors. (Python)

Tags: python, math, currency

#### This is not a question of formatting.

I'm doing a little learning/exrcize, and decided to create a "tip calculator" in Python. I am well aware that there are potential rounding errors with certain numbers, using floats, etc. And I know that I should deal with pennies/integers only, as much as possible.

How can I properly avoid rounding while calculating a total (in USD), based on percentages?

Ideally, I'd have a function that takes a `percentage` and `subtotal` and returns the "tip" total (based on percentage) and new ticket total -- **doing the money-math without rounding, just like I would if I were doing it on paper** / on my calculator.

### Currently, I have something like this:

```
import decimal

def get_tip(percentage, pennies_sub_total):
    """"
    param percentage: I suspect this should be int() or decimal.Decimal. I'm not aware of a condition that would make it matter either way. You? 
    param pennies_sub_total = int()
    """
    percentage = decimal.Decimal(percentage)
    pennies_sub_total = decimal.Decimal(pennies_sub_total)  # Unnecessary use of Decimal?
    tip = (pennies_sub_total * percentage) / 100
    total = (pennies_sub_total + tip)
    return {'tip': tip, 'total': total}
```

... which seems to work, but I'm not sure how to rigorously test it -- so I came here for code review. **Am I overlooking anything obvious? Have I done this in a way that I should be confident in?**

### Update

Given the questions raised in one of the answers (https://stackoverflow.com/a/18751401/26196), I will attempt to address them, if that helps:

> 1. What is the type of percentage?
> 2. What is the type of pennies_sub_total? (edit - you did mention this was int)
> 3. Does percentage after the assignment have the same type as it was when passed in.
> 4. Do you plan for handling them coming in as Decimal, int, float, str?
> 5. Then you have questions to answer, the type of tip and total. 100 in the "formula" will be an int. What will the type of tip be?
> 6. As pointed out, you also have to determine whether a 1.8855 is the result you want for 15% of 12.57.

1. `int` or `decimal.Decimal`. I'm not sure that it matters between those two...?
2. `int`, but that question was already resolved.
3. Maybe? It's not returned. If I'm screwing up some scope stuff, let me know. This isn't intended to modify any variables outside the "scope" of this function.
4. See 1 & 2.
5. `tip` should probably return as a `decimal.Decimal`, or an integer of "pennies". In the existing code example, I believe I ambiguously left it as float. This particular line/assignment is a specific place to offer an answer, because it's where the "real" work is done.
6. I *thought* my question made it pretty clear that anything smaller than a penny should be ignored. "1.8855" is a fine result as long as whatever math handles the "subtotal+tip" portion doesn't round up/down, and simply adds up the pennies -- again, another great spot to offer advice, because that's what I want to be sure I'm doing correctly.

Comment: "without rounding, just like ... on paper" doesn't make sense.  What's the 15% tip for a 1 cent meal?

Comment: "so I came here for code review" --> try [codereview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @Teepeemm I forget I'm dealing with programmers: "0" is the answer to your question.

Comment: @askewchan Didn't realize that was a thing. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: @BurhanKhalid Perhaps I corrected my code in a previous edit, but I don't see that line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
>>> import decimal

>>> decimal.Decimal('1.99')
Decimal('1.99')
```

> The purpose of this module is to support arithmetic using familiar
>       "schoolhouse" rules and to avoid some of the tricky representation
>       issues associated with binary floating point.  The package is especially
>       useful for financial applications or for contexts where users have
>       expectations that are at odds with binary floating point (for instance,
>       in binary floating point, 1.00 % 0.1 gives 0.09999999999999995 instead
>       of the expected Decimal('0.00') returned by decimal floating point).

Comment: Why is the text in your answer highlighted? If this is a quote, can you please cite the source? Thank you.

Comment: it's in the docs of the decimal module; help(decimal) will do :-)

Comment: I'm sure you're right, but I don't see that quote in the latest version of the docs: http://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html#module-decimal (currently).

Comment: Also, since I'm already using the decimal module, and have looked over the documentation (explicitly shown in my question) I'm not sure how the console code was supposed to be an "answer". I am at the stage where I know "what I'm doing" but looking for input/confirmation that "I'm doing it right", I guess.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the original question at all... which I admit is not well scoped.

Answer (score 1):

You have a number of issues and have left some issues for us to guess.

1. What is the type of percentage?
2. What is the type of pennies_sub_total (edit - you did mention this was int)
3. Does percentage after the assignment have the same type as it was when passed in.
4. Do you plan for handling them coming in as Decimal, int, float, str?
5. Then you have questions to answer, the type of tip and total.
   100 in the "formula" will be an int. What will the type of tip be?
6. As pointed out, you also have to determine whether a 1.8855 is the result you want for 15% of 12.57.

To answer these questions, I would suggest you just walk through what is the function and display results running in the python interpreter. For example,

```
>>> tip = (pennies_sub_total * percentage) / 100
>>> tip
```

Comment: As I hoped to convey in the question, I don't have complete confidence in the existing solution -- therefore, I gave (what I thought was) a decent "example", purposely a bit ambiguous, so as to leave room for corrected solutions. I will attempt to resolve the issues you pointed out, and see how it fares from there.

Comment: Great questions. I attempted to specifically address them in an edit.

Answer (score 1):

The precision of the arithmetic is not an issue: if the result is off by 10<sup>-14</sup> cents it's close enough. The real problem is rounding the result for display, so that you don't show more digits than what are significant. That's an easy problem to solve:

```
>>> print "tip: %.2f total: %.2f" % (0.15*12.57, 1.15*12.57)
tip: 1.89 total: 14.46
```

Comment: When I use a calculator and do "12.57 * 0.15" I get "1.8855" - as expected. Thus, I would add "1.88" to "12.57" to get a total of "14.45" -- am I doing my table math wrong, and screwing restaurants out of pennies?